# Is anisotropic BSDF different to principled BSDF w anisotropy?

Tags: materials

I have [a simple sphere](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rip8mtf3r2zfpgj/compare_anisotropic_b279.blend?dl=0). Half of it has an anisotropic BSDF material, the other half has a Principled BSDF material with anisotropy. I believe I have the same settings for the two materials, but they render differently. How do I get the materials to match?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like if you play a bit with the *Principled* settings you get about the same result. I can't tell you more as I don't know anything about anisotropy   ;)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a difference in the formulae for calculating the U and V roughnesses. The *Principled BSDF* copies the anisotropy controls of the Disney BSDF.

Here is the code that calculates the roughnesses for the *Anisotropic BSDF* from the source code.

```
if (aniso < 0.0) {
    roughness_u = roughness / (1.0 + aniso);
    roughness_v = roughness * (1.0 + aniso);
  }
  else {
    roughness_u = roughness * (1.0 - aniso);
    roughness_v = roughness / (1.0 - aniso);
  }
```

With the *Pricipled BSDF* the code looks a bit different.

```
float aspect = sqrt(1.0 - Anisotropic * 0.9);
float r2 = Roughness * Roughness;

float alpha_x = r2 / aspect;
float alpha_y = r2 * aspect;
```

`alpha_x` and `alpha_y` are the U and V roughnesses.

A while back, I made a node group that can convert U and V roughnesses to *Roughness* and *Anisotrop**y*** (for *Anisotropic BSDF*) or *Roughness* and *Anisotrop**ic*** (for *Principled BSDF*)
[image]

This node group will output the *Anisotrop**y*** and *Anisotrop**ic*** differently so that the roughnesses are consistent across both nodes.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[The manual section on the Principled Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/principled.html) says

> Compared to the Anisotropic BSDF node, the direction of highlight elongation is rotated by 90°. Add 0.25 to the value to correct.

Comment: There is still a bit of a difference. Can you tell why? 
https://www.screencast.com/t/7t0HoxB7xt

Comment: Part of the difference there is the specular component of the *Principled BSDF* node.